# Inputting 6 lines in Java

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I’m trying to read 6 lines of user input, but I can’t get them to print correctly.

I first did this:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String name, name2;
        double price, price2;
        int item, item2;

        System.out.print("Name: ");
        name = input.next();
        System.out.print("Price: ");
        price = input.nextDouble();
        System.out.print("Item Number: ");
        item = input.nextInt();
        System.out.println("");

        System.out.print("Name 2: ");
        name = input.next();
        System.out.print("Price 2: ");
        price = input.nextDouble();
        System.out.print("Item Number 2: ");
        item = input.nextInt();
        System.out.println("");
    }
}
```

And after I test it won't let me input past "Price:" (I'm on BlueJ btw).

```
Name: Jack B

Price:
```

I tried with `input.nextLine();` instead of `input.next()`, but ended up with this

```
Name: Jack B

Price: 30

Item Number: 10

Name 2: Price 2:
```

It works if the String doesn’t have spaces, but if it has one, this will happen. How do I get it to print the 6 lines normally?

Comment: Java is not JavaScript. Please tag your questions correctly.

Comment: @Xufox And output is no code ...

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102045/scanner-is-skipping-nextline-after-using-next-nextint-or-other-nextfoo

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Scanner is skipping nextLine() after using next(), nextInt() or other nextFoo()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102045/scanner-is-skipping-nextline-after-using-next-nextint-or-other-nextfoo)

Comment: @Tom That’s what `<!-- language: none -->` is for. Output is not just regular text either.

Comment: @Xufox It wasn't formatted (anymore) as "regular text".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to "flush the buffer".

Whenever you read an int, you are actually reading the string value of the integer, not including the newline character, and converting it to an int.

When you call `nextInt()`, and enter `42`, the buffer looks like this.

```
"42\n"
```

After you read the int, the buffer still contains the newline character.

```
"\n"
```

When you call `nextLine()`, it reads the newline character from the buffer, and returns an empty String.

The solution. Call `nextLine()` after reading each `int`, `double`, etc., to read and discard the trailing newline character.

```
int i = input.nextInt(); // read integer value
input.nextLine(); // read and throw away newline character
```

Answer (score 0):

Two suggestions:

1. Use `nextLine` instead of `next` to read the whole line including spaces.
2. Use an extra `nextLine` after you do the first `nextInt`. This is needed to consume an extra line break that you enter but is not consumed by nextInt.

See the following workig snippet:

```
    Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
    String name, name2;
    double price, price2;
    int item, item2;

    System.out.print("Name: ");
    name = input.nextLine();
    System.out.print("Price: ");
    price = input.nextDouble();
    System.out.print("Item Number: ");
    item = input.nextInt();
    System.out.println("");

    input.nextLine();
    System.out.print("Name 2: ");
    name = input.nextLine();
    System.out.print("Price 2: ");
    price = input.nextDouble();
    System.out.print("Item Number 2: ");
    item = input.nextInt();
    System.out.println("");
```